# Antonym for ameliorate

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I have been searching online for a particular word; that approximates to an antonym of ameliorate. I am after a specific word.

> [ameliorate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ameliorate) verb
>
> to make better 
> Synonyms ameliorate, amend, better, enhance, enrich, help, meliorate, perfect, refine, upgrade
> Related Words correct, emend, rectify, reform, remediate, remedy; edit, fine-tune, redraft, refurbish, rehab, rehabilitate, revamp, revise, rework; beef (up), boost, fortify, intensify, reinforce (also reenforce), strengthen; fine, hone, polish; retouch, touch up
> Near Antonyms damage, endamage, harm, hurt, impair, injure, spoil, tarnish, vitiate; blemish, blight, deface, disfigure, flaw, mar; diminish, lessen, lower, reduce
> Antonyms worsen

The word is eluding me... it sounds like detiliorate.. not deteriorate. My example is, probably, misleading, as my searches on google are not throwing up any alternative words.. So I'm probably way off base.

Anyone know the word I am trying to remember?

Comment: _Deteriorate_ is usually intransitive, but the transitive meaning ("To make worse or of inferior quality; to lower in character or excellence; to worsen.") is older, and I certainly use it occasionally.

Comment: The lation _melior_ (better) is the comparative of _bonus_ (good), so one could, if so inclined, form the antonym based on the comparative of _malus_ (bad), _peior_, leading to _apeiorate_. When I did the same to find an antonym for _optimal_ (being _pessimal_), the result turned out to be in dictionaries. This time, no such luck. That's why I keep this as a comment, not an answer. _Apeiorate_ is certainly not the word anyone was trying to remember.

Comment: @oerkelens: It would likely be \*_apejorate_ (cf _pejorative_), but it's still not in any dictionary I've come across :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`exacerbate`

```
From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

  exacerbate
      v 1: make worse; "This drug aggravates the pain" [syn: {worsen},
           {aggravate}, {exacerbate}, {exasperate}] [ant:
           {ameliorate}, {amend}, {better}, {improve}, {meliorate}]
      2: exasperate or irritate [syn: {exacerbate}, {exasperate},
         {aggravate}]
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is an antonym that ends with an -*iorate* because the words *ameliorate* and *meliorate* derive from a single stem (see below). The closest etymological antonym is ***aggravate***

*ameliorate* comes from French *meilleur* and [*ameliorer*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/am%C3%A9liorer) - the direct French antonym for this word is [*aggraver*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggraver) meaning '*to make worse'*.

Answer (score 1):

After I posted this, I remembered the word!

[**deleterious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deleterious)

> del·e·te·ri·ous adjective \ˌde-lə-ˈtir-ē-əs\
>   : damaging or harmful
>
> Synonyms
>   adverse, bad, baleful, baneful, damaging, dangerous, harmful, detrimental, evil, hurtful, ill, injurious, mischievous, nocuous, noxious, pernicious, prejudicial, wicked
>   Antonyms
>   anodyne, benign, harmless, hurtless, innocent, innocuous, inoffensive, safe
>   Related Words
>   hostile, inimical, unfriendly; contagious, deadly, infectious, infective, pestiferous, pestilent, pestilential, poisonous, venomous; insidious, menacing, ominous, sinister, threatening; hazardous, imperiling (or imperilling), jeopardizing, parlous, perilous, risky, unsafe, unsound; nasty, noisome, unhealthful, unhealthy, unwholesome; destructive, fatal, killer, lethal, malignant, ruinous
>   Near Antonyms
>   advantageous, beneficial, useful; favorable, good, propitious; curative, healthful, healthy, helpful, palliative, remedial, salubrious, salutary, wholesome; secure, sound; benignant; noncorrosive, nondestructive, nonfatal, noninfectious, nonlethal, nonpoisonous, nonpolluting, nontoxic, nonvenomous

Comment: This can't be right. _Ameliorate_ is a verb; _deleterious_ isn't.

Comment: They don't look exact opposite meaning either

Comment: @BrianHooper but the OP did say in his question "sounds like detiliorate". :)